Make a Swift generic method take optional or unwrapped associated types
I have the following code that basically converts strings to Enums where applicable:
        func value(for key: String) -> String? {
            return values(for: key).first
        }

        func anyValue<T: LosslessStringConvertible>(for key: String) -> T? {
            guard let value = value(for: key) else { return nil }

            return T(value)
        }

        func enumValue<EnumType, ValueType>(for key: String) -> EnumType? where EnumType: RawRepresentable<ValueType>, ValueType: LosslessStringConvertible {
            guard let value: ValueType = anyValue(for: key) else { return nil }

            return EnumType(rawValue: value)
        }


        func enumValue<EnumType, ValueType>(for key: String) -> EnumType? where EnumType: RawRepresentable<ValueType?>, ValueType: LosslessStringConvertible {
            guard let value: ValueType = anyValue(for: key) else { return nil }

            return EnumType(rawValue: value)
        }

Is it possible to combine the two versions of enumValue into one generic without any new protocols or extensions? I want to be able to use it with a RawRepresentable<Int> as well as a RawRepresentable<Int?>.

You can't write one function without a new extension or new protocols because Int and Optional<Int> are different types.
But there is a simple way to do it with only one extension.:
extension Optional: LosslessStringConvertible where Wrapped: LosslessStringConvertible { }

Then you can use one method that will work for both optional and non-optional types:
func enumValue<EnumType: RawRepresentable>(value: EnumType.RawValue) -> EnumType? where EnumType.RawValue: LosslessStringConvertible { }


In most cases, Swift will let you pass an Int to an Int? parameter. I assume it just automatically wraps the argument before passing it, so it would be more complicated to acheive the same for nested optionals. I don't really want Optional to conform to LosslessStringConvertible – I think I want to be able to only write the optional version and have EnumType wrapped somehow so that ValueType are auto-converted to ValueType? in the way they are when assigned to a ValueType?. Writing it out like that, though, I can see why Swift doesn't support that.
